# Isomorphism of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I want to show that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_8)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

The group $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is cylcic and is generated by one element. The possible generators are $1,3,5,7$.

Each automorphism maps each of the element of the set $\{1,3,5,7\}$ to one of the element $\{1,3,5,7\}$, right?

But how can we show that that the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ ?

Answer (score 2):

An automorphism $f:\Bbb Z_8 \to \Bbb Z_8$ is determined by $f(1)$ (prove it). Since $1$ is a generator and generators must map to generators, $f(1)\in \{1,3,5,7\}$. So there are 4 automorphisms. Since the only groups of order 4 are $\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$, you just have to show that $Aut(\Bbb Z_8)$ has no element of order 4.

Comment: You can also just write down an explicit isomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by "An automorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}_8\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_8$ is determined by $f(1)$" ?

Comment: I mean that if $f,g:\Bbb{Z}_8\to \Bbb Z_8$ are automorphisms (or homomorphisms for that matter), then $f=g$ is equivalent to $f(1)=g(1)$. To prove this just think about $f(n)=f(1+...+1)=f(1)+...+f(1)$ (with $n$ copies of 1).

Comment: Ah ok... How did you conclude that there are $4$ automorphisms? Because there are $4$ elements in the set $\{1,3,5,7\}$ ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right.

Comment: Do the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ have order $4$? What order have the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ ?

Comment: Not all elements of $\Bbb Z_4$ have order 4, however there are elements of order $4$, which doesn't happen in $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: We have that the possible generators of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ are $1,3,5,7$. The automorphisms map one generator to one of the others. So, the automorphisms are the following functions: $$f_1(x)=x, f_2(x)=x+2, f_3(x)=x+4, f_4(x)=x-2$$ Could we show that the two groups are isomorphic to each other by defining the function $$h:\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_8)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2 \text{ with } \\ f_1\mapsto (0,0) \\ f_2\mapsto (0,1) \\ f_3\mapsto (1,0) \\ f_4\mapsto (1,1)$$ and show that it is bijective and an homomorphism?

Comment: Or can we not do that in that way?

Comment: If $f(1)=3$ then $f(x)=3x$ not $x+3$.

Comment: So, do we define the following function? $$h:\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_8)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2 \text{ with } \\ f_1\mapsto (0,0) \\ f_2\mapsto (0,1) \\ f_3\mapsto (1,0) \\ f_4\mapsto (1,1)$$ where $$f_1(x)=x, \ f_2(x)=3x, \ f_3(x)=5x\equiv -3x, \ f_4(x)=7x\equiv -x$$

Comment: Yes, that's perfect.